# Isoline v8 not returning different polygons with different departure times

Tags: routes, here-api

I've been using the HERE v8 isoline for a few months without problems but now the departureTime seems to have no effect anymore. Changing the date, time, removing it completely or setting it as "any" seems to return the same polygon.

below is an example call, just add your apiKey at the end to test and then play with the departureTime to see what I mean.

```
https://isoline.router.hereapi.com/v8/isolines?transportMode=car&origin=52.51578,13.37749&departureTime=2020-05-10T09:30:00&range[type]=time&range[values]=300
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Hi, I've filed a bug for this issue. Will monitor it and let you know once it is fixed.